# iOS-Swift, Stripe createEphemeralKeys Returning Google SignIn Page

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

Hi I am trying to get ephemeral key using Firebase cloud function, below is my Swift file & node’s file

**.swift**

```
class VIARestClient: NSObject, STPEphemeralKeyProvider {

static let restClient = VIARestClient();

func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {

    let URLString = API_ENDPOINT + CREATE_EMPHEREMAL_KEY as String;

    let custID = "cus_CEPMtLbshv7EaP";        

    var requestData : [String : String]? = [String : String]()
    requestData?.updateValue(apiVersion, forKey: "api_version");
    requestData?.updateValue(custID, forKey: "customerId");

    submitDataToURL(URLString, withMethod: "POST", requestData: requestData!);

}



func submitDataToURL(_ urlString : String, withMethod method : String, requestData data : [String : Any]) {
    do {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return};

        let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 60)

        urlRequest.httpMethod = method;
        urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")  // the request is JSON
        urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")        // the expected response is also JSON

        let httpBodyData : Data?

        try httpBodyData = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: []);

        urlRequest.httpBody = httpBodyData;

        let dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (responseData, urlResponse, error) in
            print("responseData \(String(describing: responseData))");

            print("urlResponse \(String(describing: urlResponse))");

        })

        dataTask.resume();
    }
    catch {
        print("Excetion in submitDataToURL")
    }   
}
```

nodejs

```
app.post('/createEphemeralKeys', (req, res) => {

  const stripe_version = req.body.api_version;
  if (!stripe_version) {
    res.status(400).end();
    return;
  }
  stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
    {customer: req.body.customerId},
    {stripe_version: stripe_version}
  ).then((key) => {
    res.status(200).send(key);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).end();
  });
});
```

When I perform REST API call then in response I am getting Google SignIn URL, Even I tried in POSTMAN, the response is coming plain HTML text. I am using `STPCustomerContext` & `STPPaymentContext`, here spinner continues to spin.

This is logs in xcode debugger.

```
    (<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x170237a20> { URL: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fappengine.google.com%2F_ah%2Fconflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fus-central1-devdatabasefresh.cloudfunctions.net%2FcreateEphemeralKeys } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Thu, 01 Feb 2018 17:44:46 GMT";
    Expires = "Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = GSE;
    "Set-Cookie" = "GAPS=1:DPWaQyfDlbfYxiI2mrsbqszeoBaWZg:2mBfv5V9UXY2rkxf;Path=/;Expires=Sat, 01-Feb-2020 17:44:46 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly;Priority=HIGH";
    "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
    "alt-svc" = "hq=\":443\"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"41,39,38,37,35\"";
    "content-security-policy" = "script-src 'nonce-Gb8VeHY/ULjN1Yy9ofK4/tWy+I0' 'unsafe-inline' 'strict-dynamic' https: http: 'unsafe-eval';object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';report-uri /cspreport";
    "x-auto-login" = "realm=com.google&args=service%3Dah%26continue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fappengine.google.com%252F_ah%252Fconflogin%253Fcontinue%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fus-central1-devdatabasefresh.cloudfunctions.net%252FcreateEphemeralKeys";
    "x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
    "x-frame-options" = DENY;
    "x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block";
} })
```

I followed this youtube video.

[Getting Started with Stripe! (Swift 3 in Xcode : Part 1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdszUvzroxQ)

I tried to use `Alamofire's`  `.responseJSON` but it is failing.

Please let me know where am I making mistake or any hint/documentation will be very helpful.

Comment: it looks like you got a status code of `200` back from your call to your cloud `createEphemeralKeys` function.  If you go into the Stripe dashboard, do you see anything appearing for those cloud requests under the "Logs" section?

Comment: Stripe Dashboard does node have any logs section, 

I Took out Firebase cloud functions & tested with POSTMAN `createEphemeralKeys` function in http://localhost:8080/createEphemeralKeys, interestingly control is reaching in both `.then` & `.catch({})` Clousure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my approach for nodejs code is not correct, as I was using express, later changed the code implementation with below code.

```
exports.createEphemeralKeys = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
var api_version = req.body.api_version;
var customerId = req.body.customerId;

if (!api_version) {
  res.status(400).end();
  return;
}

stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
  { customer: customerId },
  { stripe_version: api_version }, 

  function(err, key) {
    return res.send(key);
  });   
});
```

And the output log is as follows

```
{ 
  id: 'ephkey_1BramAFjruqsvjkVQGdZLiV5',
  object: 'ephemeral_key',
  associated_objects: [ { type: 'customer', id: 'cus_CEPMtLbshv7EaP' } ],
  created: 1517701830,
  expires: 1517705430,
  livemode: false,
  secret: 'ek_test_YWNjdF8xQmxUb0FGanJ1cXN2amtWLHVPcUdMN3d4UEhncW1sQkNJYmlOdzhwUGdjVUxOd1Y' 
}
```

the swift file looks like this.

```
class VIARestClient: NSObject, STPEphemeralKeyProvider {

static let restClient = VIARestClient();

func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {

    let URLString = API_ENDPOINT + CREATE_EMPHEREMAL_KEY as String;

    let custID = "cus_CEPMtLbshv7EaP";        

    var requestData : [String : String]? = [String : String]()
    requestData?.updateValue(apiVersion, forKey: "api_version");
    requestData?.updateValue(custID, forKey: "customerId");

    submitDataToURL(URLString, withMethod: "POST", requestData: requestData!) { (jsonResponse, err) in
        if err != nil {
            completion(nil, err)
        }
        else {
            completion(jsonResponse, nil)
        }
    }

}



func submitDataToURL(_ urlString : String, withMethod method : String, requestData data : [String : Any], completion : @escaping (_ jsonResponse : [String : Any], _ err: Error?) -> Void) {
    do {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return};

        let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 60)

        urlRequest.httpMethod = method;
        urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")  // the request is JSON
        urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")        // the expected response is also JSON

        let httpBodyData : Data?

        try httpBodyData = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: []);

        urlRequest.httpBody = httpBodyData;

        let dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (responseData, urlResponse, error) in
            print("responseData \(String(describing: responseData))");

            print("urlResponse \(String(describing: urlResponse))");

            if error == nil {
                do {
                    let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData!, options: []) as! [String : Any];
                    print(response);
                    completion(response, nil);
                }
                catch {
                    print("Exception")
                    let response : [String : Any] = [String : Any]()
                    completion(response, error);
                }
            }
            else {
                let response : [String : Any] = [String : Any]()
                completion(response, error);
            }
        });

        dataTask.resume();
    }
    catch {
        print("Excetion in submitDataToURL")
    }

  }
 }
```

Comment: I literally tried this and it doesn't work for me, how did you implement this and have it work successfully? Did you call the `createCustomerKey` somewhere else?

Comment: No, `createCustomerKey` function is in protocol `STPEphemeralKeyProvider`, this protocol is responsible for firing it