# Hooking firebase with stripe, API_ENDPOINT and CREATE_EMPHEREMAL_KEY

Tags: ios, swift, api, stripe-payments

I have googled in order to solve one of my problems with hooking firebase with stripe. However, I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569395/ios-swift-stripe-createephemeralkeys-returning-google-signin-page), does anybody know what `API_ENDPOINT` & `CREATE_EMPHEREMAL_KEY` is supposed to be in following line:

```
let URLString = API_ENDPOINT + CREATE_EMPHEREMAL_KEY as String;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: probably constants that when combined represent the http endpoint that triggers a cloud function

Comment: agreed.  almost definitely some kind of link to your ephemeral key provider code.